# GCP provided code snippets to both subscribe and publish mqtt in the same app doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

In my Node.js app, I can successfully publish telemetry/state topics **or** subscribe to config/command topics, but can't both publish and subscribe.

Both Node.js code snippets that appear below are from
https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge

The subscribe code is as follows -

```
// const deviceId = `myDevice`;
// const registryId = `myRegistry`;
// const region = `us-central1`;
// const algorithm = `RS256`;
// const privateKeyFile = `./rsa_private.pem`;
// const serverCertFile = `./roots.pem`;
// const mqttBridgeHostname = `mqtt.googleapis.com`;
// const mqttBridgePort = 8883;
// const messageType = `events`;
// const numMessages = 5;

// The mqttClientId is a unique string that identifies this device. For Google
// Cloud IoT Core, it must be in the format below.
const mqttClientId = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${region}/registries/${registryId}/devices/${deviceId}`;

// With Google Cloud IoT Core, the username field is ignored, however it must be
// non-empty. The password field is used to transmit a JWT to authorize the
// device. The "mqtts" protocol causes the library to connect using SSL, which
// is required for Cloud IoT Core.
const connectionArgs = {
  host: mqttBridgeHostname,
  port: mqttBridgePort,
  clientId: mqttClientId,
  username: 'unused',
  password: createJwt(projectId, privateKeyFile, algorithm),
  protocol: 'mqtts',
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
  ca: [readFileSync(serverCertFile)],
};

// Create a client, and connect to the Google MQTT bridge.
const iatTime = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000);
const client = mqtt.connect(connectionArgs);

// Subscribe to the /devices/{device-id}/config topic to receive config updates.
// Config updates are recommended to use QoS 1 (at least once delivery)
client.subscribe(`/devices/${deviceId}/config`, {qos: 1});

// Subscribe to the /devices/{device-id}/commands/# topic to receive all
// commands or to the /devices/{device-id}/commands/<subfolder> to just receive
// messages published to a specific commands folder; we recommend you use
// QoS 0 (at most once delivery)
client.subscribe(`/devices/${deviceId}/commands/#`, {qos: 0});

// The MQTT topic that this device will publish data to. The MQTT topic name is
// required to be in the format below. The topic name must end in 'state' to
// publish state and 'events' to publish telemetry. Note that this is not the
// same as the device registry's Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
const mqttTopic = `/devices/${deviceId}/${messageType}`;

client.on('connect', success => {
  console.log('connect');
  if (!success) {
    console.log('Client not connected...');
  } else if (!publishChainInProgress) {
    publishAsync(mqttTopic, client, iatTime, 1, numMessages, connectionArgs);
  }
});

client.on('close', () => {
  console.log('close');
  shouldBackoff = true;
});

client.on('error', err => {
  console.log('error', err);
});

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
  let messageStr = 'Message received: ';
  if (topic === `/devices/${deviceId}/config`) {
    messageStr = 'Config message received: ';
  } else if (topic.startsWith(`/devices/${deviceId}/commands`)) {
    messageStr = 'Command message received: ';
  }

  messageStr += Buffer.from(message, 'base64').toString('ascii');
  console.log(messageStr);
});

client.on('packetsend', () => {
  // Note: logging packet send is very verbose
});

// Once all of the messages have been published, the connection to Google Cloud
// IoT will be closed and the process will exit. See the publishAsync method.
```

and the publish code is -

```
const publishAsync = (
  mqttTopic,
  client,
  iatTime,
  messagesSent,
  numMessages,
  connectionArgs
) => {
  // If we have published enough messages or backed off too many times, stop.
  if (messagesSent > numMessages || backoffTime >= MAXIMUM_BACKOFF_TIME) {
    if (backoffTime >= MAXIMUM_BACKOFF_TIME) {
      console.log('Backoff time is too high. Giving up.');
    }
    console.log('Closing connection to MQTT. Goodbye!');
    client.end();
    publishChainInProgress = false;
    return;
  }

  // Publish and schedule the next publish.
  publishChainInProgress = true;
  let publishDelayMs = 0;
  if (shouldBackoff) {
    publishDelayMs = 1000 * (backoffTime + Math.random());
    backoffTime *= 2;
    console.log(`Backing off for ${publishDelayMs}ms before publishing.`);
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    const payload = `${argv.registryId}/${argv.deviceId}-payload-${messagesSent}`;

    // Publish "payload" to the MQTT topic. qos=1 means at least once delivery.
    // Cloud IoT Core also supports qos=0 for at most once delivery.
    console.log('Publishing message:', payload);
    client.publish(mqttTopic, payload, {qos: 1}, err => {
      if (!err) {
        shouldBackoff = false;
        backoffTime = MINIMUM_BACKOFF_TIME;
      }
    });

    const schedulePublishDelayMs = argv.messageType === 'events' ? 1000 : 2000;
    setTimeout(() => {
      const secsFromIssue = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) - iatTime;
      if (secsFromIssue > argv.tokenExpMins * 60) {
        iatTime = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000);
        console.log(`\tRefreshing token after ${secsFromIssue} seconds.`);

        client.end();
        connectionArgs.password = createJwt(
          argv.projectId,
          argv.privateKeyFile,
          argv.algorithm
        );
        connectionArgs.protocolId = 'MQTT';
        connectionArgs.protocolVersion = 4;
        connectionArgs.clean = true;
        client = mqtt.connect(connectionArgs);

        client.on('connect', success => {
          console.log('connect');
          if (!success) {
            console.log('Client not connected...');
          } else if (!publishChainInProgress) {
            publishAsync(
              mqttTopic,
              client,
              iatTime,
              messagesSent,
              numMessages,
              connectionArgs
            );
          }
        });

        client.on('close', () => {
          console.log('close');
          shouldBackoff = true;
        });

        client.on('error', err => {
          console.log('error', err);
        });

        client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
          console.log(
            'message received: ',
            Buffer.from(message, 'base64').toString('ascii')
          );
        });

        client.on('packetsend', () => {
          // Note: logging packet send is very verbose
        });
      }
      publishAsync(
        mqttTopic,
        client,
        iatTime,
        messagesSent + 1,
        numMessages,
        connectionArgs
      );
    }, schedulePublishDelayMs);
  }, publishDelayMs);
};
```

I am wondering if anyone has gotten their Node.js app to both successfully publish and subscribe with Google Cloud.  If so, what might I be missing?

Comment: Please [clarify your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (i.e. what does "can't both publish and subscribe" mean?; do you get an error, if so what). Looking at your code I'm guessing the issue is that you connect twice (and as the second connection uses the same `clientId` the broker will drop the first connection). There should be no need to connect a second time (generally I would connect when the app starts and leave the connection open until the app is terminated).

Comment: Hello @nanste. Is the above suggestion helpful? Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: My app is only connecting one time.  I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Again please edit your post and clarify the issue. Currently you have provided two bits of code (subscribe and publish) but we cannot see you are combining them (both bits of code currently include `mqtt.connect` hence my assumption). Ideally edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).